# Why does Google Chrome (v40) has so many processes open?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, crash

I've recently upgraded my Google Chrome to the newest version (38 -> 40) and I'm experiencing system level crashes. This mostly happens when I have two windows and more than a handful of tabs open.

Currently, just rebooted after a crash and restored my Chrome session, I have 2 windows and 20 tabs overall (this time I stopped most of them before even getting completely loaded).
I also have 8 extensions.

What's bothering me is the **300 child processes** under the main `google-chrome-stable` process!!

I understand the logic of "one process per tab" but my experience is each tab (and extension) has around 10 child processes plus a number of other childs that are not associated to any tabs!

What is Google Chrome doing? Is this all normal?
Maybe the crashes are not related to the new version of Chrome?

Comment: What extentions do you have?

Comment: Also, try pressing ctrl+shift+esc to open task manager in chrome and telling us what's shown in it. A screenshot of it perhaps?

Comment: @TheKB I will update the question with a list of the extensions. The Chrome Task Manager doesn't show any task out of the ordinary. I've got my tabs, Extensions, the main `Browser` process and a `GPU Process`. Though I'm not sure why do Tabs' memory usage is so high! The superuser.com tab uses more than 60MB of memory, gmail 164MB at the moment!

Comment: I think that memory usage is about normal because of all the flash/html(5)/javascript /css going on in the background, not to mention ads or the actual page itself (text, images, and videos). But, I am on mobile right now, so I can't test this myself.

Comment: I just don't understand their design decisions! e.g. why does the `ColorZilla` (color picker) extension or `Awesome Screenshot` or `Markdown Here` has to be open all the time!? I have more than 100MBs of memory assigned to extensions that don't do anything unless asked from!

Comment: I would think the extention would be loaded (using ram) so that when you want to use it, its already loaded up and ready to use.

Comment: Yeah, but it's just a menu that runs a script on the page and they are all on the local disk... Dunno! I'm not a chromium dev. Perhaps there is some reason to it. But I'm sure it can be enhanced.